# SQL Multiply Case Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement that has parts where I do Case Count on certain conditions:

```
select casedate
     , category
     , casenumber 
     , IncidentInfo 
     , num2report1
     , notes 
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat1=1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 1'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat2=2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 2'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat3=3 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 3'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat4=4 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 4'
from incident
where casedate between '12/01/2017' and '12/31/2017'
group by casenumber
       , casedate
       , category
       , notes
       , incidentinfo
       , num2report1
order by casedate desc
```

What I need to do is take that count number for the category and multiply it by the num2report1 field.

I'm struggling to get something working. What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: When you say take the count number for the category do you mean just the field category or each field called category? I.E. category 2 category 3 etc

Comment: Do you get an error when you try simple multiplication `*`?    What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select casedate, category , casenumber , IncidentInfo , 
       num2report1, notes , 
       num2report1*COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat1=1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 1', 
       num2report1*COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat2=2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 2',
       num2report1*COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat3=3 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 3',
       num2report1*COUNT(CASE WHEN geocat4=4 THEN 1 END) AS 'Category 4'
from incident
where casedate between '12/01/2017' and '12/31/2017'
group by casenumber, casedate, category, notes, incidentinfo, num2report1
order by casedate desc
```

Incidentally, this should give the same result:

```
select casedate, category , casenumber , IncidentInfo , 
       num2report1, notes , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN geocat1=1 THEN num2report1 END) AS 'Category 1', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN geocat2=2 THEN num2report1 END) AS 'Category 2',
       SUM(CASE WHEN geocat3=3 THEN num2report1 END) AS 'Category 3',
       SUM(CASE WHEN geocat4=4 THEN num2report1 END) AS 'Category 4'
from incident
where casedate between '12/01/2017' and '12/31/2017'
group by casenumber, casedate, category, notes, incidentinfo, num2report1
order by casedate desc
```

Comment: Thanks! The num2report1*COUNT works. I appreciate the hep.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need :

```
select casedate, category, casenumber, IncidentInfo, num2report1, notes, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 1', 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 2', 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat3 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 3',
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat4 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 4'
      num2report1 * COUNT(*)  AS t_count
from incident
where casedate between '12/01/2017' and '12/31/2017'
group by casedate, category, casenumber, IncidentInfo, num2report1, notes
order by casedate desc;
```

However, i supsect something like that :

```
select casedate, category, casenumber, IncidentInfo, num2report1, notes, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 1', 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 2', 
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat3 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 3',
      SUM(CASE WHEN geocat4 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Category 4',
      num2report1 * cnt AS t_count
from incident cross join 
     (select count(distinct category) as cnt from incident) as cnt
. . . ;
```